# SQL query shows good database values, but LINQ to Entity framework brings a null value from nowhere

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm having a really strange problem here, and i dont have any clue why.

I'm supposed to make small localdb console app in C#. The goal is to enter persons (teachers, actually) in the DB, with a certain amount of information.

I have a few classes, but 2 of them are important here: Certification and Notation.
Certifications are, well, certifications of the professors.

The code for these classes is this:

```
class Certification
{
    public int CertificationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public string CertificationName { get; set; }
    public virtual Notation Notation { get; set; }    
}    
class Notation
{
    public int NotationID {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}
}
```

Nothing too dangerous. Through migrations i made my database, and they look like they should:

Certification:

```
CertificationID (PK)
CertificationName
Course_CourseID (FK to another class, course)
Notation_NotationID (FK to notations)
Teacher_TeacherID (FK to the teachers)
```

Notations:

```
NotationID (PK)
Note
```

My program allows me to add teachers, with all the informations i need, and for example, their certifications. Here, i made some dummy teacher, with a dummy certification.
If i call SELECT * FROM Certification , i get exactly what i should get, a single line like this:

```
CertificationID = 6
CertificationName = placeholder
Course_CourseID = 13
Notation_NotationID = 12
Teacher_TeacherID = 5
```

Everything is correct in this. CourseID links to an actual course in the database, NotationID in an actual note, and Teacher to an actual teacher too. Everything is fine!

Now, i just want to show the certifications of our teacher:

```
var certifs = from c in db.Certifications where c.Teacher.TeacherID == item.TeacherID select c;

foreach(var v in certifs )
{
    var course = (from c in db.Courses where c.CourseID == v.Course.CourseID select c).First();
    var note = (from n in db.Notations where n.NotationID == v.Notation.NotationID select n.NotationID).First();

    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + v.CertificationName + ", related to the " + course.CourseName + " course, with a note of " + note);

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

And it doesn't work. When my foreach loop starts, my first item in the loop doesn't have any reference to a notation. Everything else is fine: the foreign keys for the course and the teachers are here, and valid, but for the notation, i only get a null value. So my certification item looks more like:

```
CertificationID = 6
CertificationName = placeholder
Course_CourseID = 13
Notation_NotationID = null
Teacher_TeacherID = 5
```

Basically, if i do a SQL Query, my row in the database is perfectly fine, but calling it through the entity framework (and LINQ) returns a null value for the notation. (which throws an exception when calling var note etc....

Does anybody have an idea about this? I'm really stuck on this.

I'm sorry if my English isn't good enough. If you guys need more information, just ask.

Anwsered by JC:

Lazy loading isnt working properly. Eager loading solves the problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you aren't populating your navigation properties when you retrieve the Certification entities. Then you try to access them and they're null.

You either need to make sure lazy loading is turned on:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; //In your DbContext's constructor
```

in which case just accessing the Course and Notification references should cause them to be populated in separate database transactions...

...or you need to employ eager loading when querying against the DbSet:

```
var certifs = from c in db.Certifications.Include(c=>c.Course).Include(c=>c.Notation) where ...
```

Which will cause Course and Notation to be loaded at the same time Certifications is loaded all in one database transaction.

Comment: Just a question: does the `First()` not cause the data to load?

Comment: You're calling First() against the Notations and Courses DbSets, but within those queries you're trying to access the Course and Notation properties of the Certification entities you retrieved outside the loop. The null exception is coming from trying to access `v.Course.CourseId` and `v.Notation.NotationId` when `v.Course` and `v.Notation` are null.

Comment: The thing is, v.Course is not null! Because i retrieve them inside the loop : foreach retrieve them.
Lazy loading is already enabled, thanks to the virtual properties in my classes (iirc).
Thats the actual problem, everything is loaded fine, except for notation.
see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/86aa1w9zjvurjv5/certstate.png

Comment: Tested adding Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
As i thought, it was already on, didnt change anything.

Comment: Looking at your question again...if lazy loading is on then the Notation and Course references should be loaded with the related Notation and Course entities when you access them. So why are you trying to explicitly query for them at all? You should be able to just omit the `from c in db.Courses ...` and `from n in db.Notations` lines and access the properties of `v.Notation` and `v.Course` directly: `v.Course.CourseName`

Comment: Indeed, and i actually already did that. I just deconstructed everything in smaller parts to target what the problem actually was. It's still not the problem: when i start foreach(v in certifs), v doesnt load my notation and puts null instead, when it's not. The problem is ONLY here. But it doesnt make any sense! If i query it through SQL, i have a complete row without any null, and when queried here, it justs fails.. Only on notation. (and i repeat, there's no problem on course, the first line var course = xxx works.)

Comment: Just in case, here is what SELECT * FROM Certifications; SELECT * FROM Notations gives:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z733n3ji8p1b2vw/certnote.png
Meaning my FK to Notation is good. Or is it?

Comment: I wonder... Inside your loop, try `context.Entry(v).Reference(c=>c.Notation).Load();`

Comment: Oh god, it worked. I keep throwing my money to the screen, but nothing's happening. I suppose you dont want it then... Do you have any idea why we have to force it to load like this?

Comment: Okay that tells me that lazy loading isn't working. The .Load() method is how you do explicit loading. I recommend you change the Certifications query to this: `from c in db.Certifications.Include(c=>c.Course).Include(c=>c.Notification) ...` which is called eager loading and causes all three entities to be populated with just one database call. There are many opinions about Lazy Loading. Mine is that any time you think it's a good idea you should think of another way. Even when it works, it's just bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
var note = (from n in db.Notations 
where n.NotationID == v.Notation.NotationID 
select n.NotationID).First();
```

you are selecting `n.NotationID` only which would return an integer only. Trying changing the `select` to `select n`